# Why isn't my attribute text showing on the front end?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

Well I have this code here and I am adding it to my `list.phtml`file to try and get the attribute text for each product to display:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('mileage') ?>
```

This code works with any attribute that has a `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` value of `dropdown` however it does not display for attributes with the value of `Text Field`.

Any idea why this might be happening?

I have the setting `Used in Product Listing` enabled for both attributes.

Thanks

Comment: did you rebuild your indexes after adding your attribute?

Comment: try this <?php echo $_product->getData('mileage'); ?>

Comment: Yes I did rebuild them, that worked @Kothari Any idea why that worked but the attribute text didn't?

Comment: `getAttributeText()` method is specifically there for dropdown type attributes. If you take a look at the method in Product model, you'll find that the method gets value index from Product data and then, finds the text for that index in respective table.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure **Visible on Product View Page on Front-end** and **Used in Product Listing** options under properties of this attribute are set to **Yes**.